# Reach concrete, numerical values for certain car values, in a car game

Tags: racing, car

I am developing a rather complicated racing car management browser game, but I think this applies to any car game.

I have 10 values. Power, acceleration, etc. that can be easily quantified by using available data (hp, 1-100 kmh time). All is well, but I have 4 values (Handling, Braking, Transmission, Front/Back-Weight) that I'm not sure how to quantify.

Would I just say X car has Y brakes were Y = 20 (arbitrarily decided because I think this car brakes Y well) and then put it in a formula with car power and weight to reach this value, or does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: How accurate is your physics model? Do you use a realistic engine 'torque curve' or do you just use a basic 0-100km/h type setup. If you use 100km/h times, perhaps you could use something like the 100km/h-0 brake times that are posted for various cars. Let me know how accurate you want the physics, and I'll try to help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Iterative empirical testing**. Add some test sliders to your GUI that control the various values you're trying to work out. Use common sense and estimate real world values to give your sliders as small a range as possible. Then, **play test**. Keep trying values, keep track of the ones you like.

Comment: That sounds like good practice for any value, but i was talking more specifically about the values i mentioned. As in what factors are considered and how are they quantified, in order to calculate with an equation the numerical value of an abstract concept like handling of a car.